# Xcode Error: Receiver type 'SimpleCellPartes' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'presentModalViewController:animated:'

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am receiving the error: Receiver type 'SimpleCellPartes' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'presentModalViewController:animated:'

the button is in a cell of a tableview and i try to deploy a new view

this is my code:

Comment: Edit your post and show us the code you have written on button press (IBAction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code when you're trying to segue to the view with your UITableView, you are trying to do something like:

```
[cell presentModalViewController: controller animated:YES];
```

But your code does not appear to be showing up.

Comment: yes, i try that, but i dont have cell Z=[[Zoom alloc]init];
        Z.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:Z animated:YES]; 
    // here displays the error}

Comment: i dont know why my code does not appear